# Como hacer para que la cobertura en sonarQube sea 0% en vez de —

Tags: sonarqube, cobertura

Tengo un proyecto en react que no tiene cobertura de pruebas unitarias. Al realizar el análisis en sonar la cobertura no aparece y al navegar en el código la cobertura de los archivos aparecen —. [image: Cobertura —].

Pasa lo mismo en proyecto angular.

Que puedo hacer para que SonarQube reporte la cobertura en 0% en vez de —?